# match '/' or '/?' to remove trailing slash regex not working as expected

Tags: regex

I have made a regex for nginx that I want to capture the URL & parameters without the `?`.  It must only match URL that contain a `?`.  It must split results into 2 groups.

My regex is: `^(.*)\?(.*)$`

It almost works but it catches the trailing slash which breaks some things.

[image]

As you can see the trailing `/` is inside capture group.  So I want to either match `?` or `/?` in a non-capturing group depending what is there but it doesn't work as expected:

Updated regex: `^(.*)(?:\/\?|\?)(.*)$`

This will always still only match the `?` I guess because it looks for smaller match first.

I can't quite conceptualize the right way to drop the training slash from capture group in a single regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*[^\/])?\/?\?(.*)$
^(.*?)\/?\?(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/srOraZ/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/srOraZ/2).

*Details*:

The `^(.*[^\/])?\/?\?(.*)$` pattern means:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*[^\/])?` - an optional Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then a char other than a `/`
- `\/?` - an optional `/` char
- `\?` - a `?` char
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

The `^(.*?)\/?\?(.*)$` means:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as ***few*** as possible
- `\/?\?(.*)$` - an optional `/`, then a `?` char, then Group 2 capturing the rest of the string.